# Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my package.json file?

Tags: json, package, syntax-error, package.json, npm-start

I have had npm and a json validator site tell me that my package.jason file is invalid. I have looked through forums and stack overflow and nothing seems to fix it. Here is the code:

```
{
"name": "linobs",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A linux streaming software",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "linobstest",
"start": "electron ."
},
"keywords": {
"obs",
"broadcast",
"open source",
"Free",
"Streaming"
},
"author": "Dustin Hacker",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

error message from website:

```
{
  "valid": false,
  "critical": "Invalid JSON - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 11 column 6 of the JSON data"
}
```

Error message from npm:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/ldhacker/Documents/Electron Project/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token , in JSON at position 183 while parsing near '...
npm ERR! JSON.parse "keywords": {
npm ERR! JSON.parse "OBS",
npm ERR! JSON.parse "Broadcast",
npm ERR! JSON.parse "Open...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ldhacker/.npm/_logs/2020-09-13T18_38_47_283Z-debug.log
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Removed the `,` after `"main": "main.js",` and now I get:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/ldhacker/Documents/Electron Project/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 103 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse "name": "linobs",
npm ERR! JSON.parse "version": "1.0.0",
npm ERR! JSON.parse '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ldhacker/.npm/_logs/2020-09-13T19_13_16_582Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the "keywords" part of the file, you should surround the keywords with `[]`, not `{}`.

For example:

```
...
"keywords": [
    "obs",
    "broadcast",
    "open source",
    "Free",
    "Streaming"
],
...
```

If you're interested in learning how the JSON format works, check out this website: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Just renamed my `package.json` to `package.json.old` and re-accomplished `npm init` and it worked after adding the `"start": "electron ."`.

I am not going to attempt to edit it again...

Comment: Or, I am at least going to make it have an open source license.